# AngularJS: How to initialise components after service finished asynchronous request

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

We're not using AngularJs as a SPA but embedded module to manage some behavior and shared data, so we're not actually utilising something like angular router. How should I initialize components only after a shared data service finished an asynchronous request? AngularJS was used with Typescript

**Angular Module**

```
import ... from '...'
import ... from '...'
...

angular.module('app-1', [])
.service('data-service', DataService)
.component('zeroDateButton', new ZeroDateButtonComponent())
.component('zeroPanel', new ZeroPanelComponent())
.component('zeroChart', new ZeroChartComponent())
```

**ASP.NET Page hosting Angular module**

*BI.aspx*

```
<asp:Content ID="standardContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
...
<zero-date-button></zero-date-button>
<zero-date-button></zero-date-button>

<zero-panel name="panel-1"></zero-panel>
<zero-panel name="panel-2"></zero-panel>
<zero-panel name="panel-3"></zero-panel>

<zero-chart></zero-chart>
...

<script src="Scripts/Components/component.app-1.js) "></script> //compiled angular module js file

</asp:Content>
```

**Page URL: https://www.example.com/BI/Zero**

#### DataService.ts

```ts
public tryGetData() {
    return $http.get(url).then((res: any) => {
        this.panels = res.panels;
    });
}
```

*ZeroPanelComponent.ts*

```ts
...
public $onInit(): void {
    this.panels = this.dataService.panels;
    this._render();
...
```

Most of the logics for this module relies on the data from the three components, so I want to fetch and store them all together in the data service, from which each component access the data they need from this service, and let the service figure out the logics and tell each of them by broadcasting the events.

Upon the components initialization(in **$onInit** method), it should display things using data retrieved from data service. The problem is component initialization is not awaiting data service to finish data fetching, so the component can't get the data they need and render nothing.

**Trial with $routeProvider**

I've seen seen lot's of people advising $routeProvider with appModule.config(), however it was not working. I'm not sure if this solution will work considering the way we use Angular, but I'm still posting the code snippet.

```
angular.module('app-1', ['ngRoute'])
.config(($routeProvider) => {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/BI/Zero', {
            template: '<zero-panel class="flex-basis-half marginBottom" panel-name="SalesSnapshot", container-id="sales-snapshot"></zero-panel>',
            resolve: {
                DataService: (DataService) => {
                    return DataService.tryGetData();
                },
            },
        });
})
.service('zero-data-service', DataService)
...
```

and I added `ng-view` directive to one  in BI.aspx

There's NO error in browser, `<zero-panel>` is not rendered and tryGetDate() is not called too. I found someone said the 'path' defined to when() is part of the URL after the # symbol. Could you verify if this is true?

In terms other solution, the most intuitive thing I can think of is broadcasting an event when data service has obtained the data, and components listen to event to fetch the data, instead of fetching during their initialization.

I appreciate if anyone can suggest if $routeProvider would work in my usecase, or suggest any other possible solution to achieve the goal.

Comment: `panels` is not a property of the $http `.then` method response object.

Comment: @georgeawg Thanks for reply. `res.panels` is alright because of how I defined the dummy data as a response. I can get `panels` but only after the $onInit in component has been run, during which the `this.dataService.panels` is undefined, because stuff in `.then(()=>{})` runs afterwards.